# How to pass input arguments to a function in an efficient way

Tags: c++

I have a structure defined as

```
typedef struct _ans{
int  **a;
int *b; double*c; int *d, int *e, float *f, double *g;} ans;
ans *temp;
```

"a" is an a two-dimensional array and for each row in this array, let the i-th row, I will define a corresponding value in the i-th element of vectors "b, c, and d, etc".

I want to create a function "func" that modifies the i-th row in array "a"; Obviously, whenever row i in "a" is modified, its corresponding values in vectors "b, c, and d, etc" should be recalculated as well.

I have two possibilities:

1- Define func as

```
func(temp->a[i], temp->b[i], temp->c[i], temp->d[i], temp->e[i], temp->f[i],temp->g[i])
```

with many input arguments but all with respect to the i-th row.
or 
2- Just pass "temp" as the only input argument of func :

```
 func(temp)
```

and then inside the function, I can easily access the i-th row and its corresponding values in other vectors b, c, etc.

I am wondering which of these two cases are more efficient, in terms of the code efficiency and computational time.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: With the first approach you will have to change your function's signature if you change your structure. As a result, all clients of the function will fail to compile. Thus, the second approach is more preferable to me.

Answer (score 2):

All that is below is generalities of course. You may have good reasons for the choices you've made so far, but they look wrong to me.

Your design is wrong, and your concern for saving computational time is misplaced. The biggest cost in software is the human one. First priority is always to make your code as simple and straightforward and understandable as possible.

There are two clear flaws in your data structure, excessive use of pointers and insufficient grouping of related items (parallel arrays in other words). This would be better

```
struct Row
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    int b;
    double c;
    int d;
    int e;
    float f;
    double g;
};

struct Ans
{
    std::vector<Row> a;
};

Ans temp;
```

With this redesign the correct place for your `func` function becomes obvious. It should be a method of the `Row` struct where it will have access to all the data it needs.

```
struct Row
{
    void func();
    std::vector<int> a;
    int b;
    double c;
    int d;
    int e;
    float f;
    double g;
};
```

Although the design is improved this solution is equivalent to your second option.

You should also work towards making the data in your structs private.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no need to `typedef` a struct in C++. Just say

```
struct ans {
    int **a;
    int *b; double*c; int *d; int *e; float *f; double *g;
};
```

Next, don't use C-style arrays, use standard containers like `std::vector`, e.g.

```
#include <vector>

struct ans {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > a;
    std::vector<int> b;
    std::vector<double> c;
    std::vector<int> d, e;
    std::vector<float> f;
    std::vector<double> g;
};
```

This way you don't have to mess with dynamic memory yourself.

And finally, just define the `temp` object, again no need to dynamically allocate it

```
ans temp;
```

---

To answer the question, passing the structure by reference would be most efficient, because it involves the least amount of data copied:

```
void func(ans &a);
```

Although, passing parameters time can usually be neglected unless it is done many times over and over again.